# cannot call button signal from abstract class

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I want to call a function when a button click. the implementation of the button is in the abstract class. but when I compile I'm getting this error.

This is my .h file of the base class

```
#ifndef HOME_H
#define HOME_H
#include<QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include<QPushButton>

class home
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  home();

  virtual void set_home_background()=0 ;
  QGraphicsScene *scene3;
  QPushButton *button3;

private slots:
  virtual void startgame1();
};

#endif // HOME_H
```

This is the base class

```
#include "home.h"
#include<QGraphicsScene>
#include<QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include "QMessageBox"

home::home()
{

}

void home::set_home_background()
{
  button3 = new QPushButton;
  QObject::connect(button3,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(startgame1()));
  QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = this->scene3->addWidget(button3);
  button3->setAutoFillBackground(true);
  button3->setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/ng.png"));
  button3->setIconSize(QSize(131,41));
  proxy->setPos(130,430);
  scene3->addItem(proxy);
}

void home::startgame1()
{
  QMessageBox q;
  q.setText("");
  q.exec();
}
```

I'm getting this error

> C:\Users\User\Documents\breakout_final\home.cpp:16: error: no matching
>   function for call to 'QObject::connect(QPushButton*&, const char*,
>   home*, const char*)'
>   QObject::connect(button3,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(startgame1()));

```
                                                                   ^
```

Comment: You have to derive from QObjcet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your code: in order to use Qt signals and slots, you should inherit your class from QObject, Q_OBJECT declaration itself is not enough:

```
#include <QObject>

class home : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    home();


    virtual void set_home_background()=0 ;
     QGraphicsScene *scene3;
     QPushButton *button3;

private slots:
    virtual void startgame1();    
};
```